# Incorrect EQ_ROWS from low % sampled statistic (but not on all columns)

Tags: sql-server, statistics

On a particular nullable guid column I am getting EQ_ROWS that are substantially incorrect (Table has 977 million rows). Default sample size is to blame - currently about .1%
Here is a single row out of the stats (the correct count(*) returns 121 for this guid)

```
RANGE_HI_KEY    RANGE_ROWS  EQ_ROWS     DISTINCT_RANGE_ROWS AVG_RANGE_ROWS
7F0334A0...     2052729     43611.33    289                 7099.937
```

On another non-nullable guid column (same database) I get almost perfect statistics (correct count(*) is 12)

```
RANGE_HI_KEY    RANGE_ROWS  EQ_ROWS     DISTINCT_RANGE_ROWS AVG_RANGE_ROWS
D1971F39...     273236.1    11.99996    187206              1.459549
```

Under what circumstances does the EQ_ROWS and AVG_RANGE_ROWS become multiplied like this?
This system has been upgrade from 2016 to 2019 recently, but a full 100% sample and then default sample statistics restores the same bad effect.

Comment: Just thinking out loud: Sample 0.1%, and you happen to encounter 43 NULLs. Now scale that 43 rows with a factor 1000 (you sampled 0.1%), which gives you 43000 NULLs. I.e., the scarceness of your NULLs is the problem along with the sample rate. You only have 0.00446% NULLs in there, hard to get good precision for that. I should add that I do not have insight to the actual algorithms for statistics collection, so plenty of speculation here.

Comment: Thanks Tibor. I did also try adding filtered statistics (which should remove the null effect). I'll keep trying to repro in lab conditions, but I've got a feeling if I drop/recreate the clustered index the problem may stop happening too (so may be related to upgrade somehow).

Comment: I doubt a filtered index helps. It gives you more than 200 steps in the histogram, but in this case the problem seems to be the sample rate. Not sure, though. Drop the cl ix will re-create all other indexes, and statistics for those will be created based on full scan. Then this happens again when you create the cl ix. Huge overkill if this problem is only with this particular stats (do an UPDATE STATISTICS with FULLSCAN or something).

Comment: I've written a statistics analyser, available at https://github.com/brettshearer/StatisticsAnalyser

I'll try and see if I can pick up more outliers/patterns.